# Django, render with link or remove template dirs when render in view

Tags: django, templates, render

hai i am newbie in django and sorry for grammar mistake
first i have some project to upload file extension `.html` to AWS S3, so in `views.py` i want to render a link i've already uploaded to AWS S3. ex: `render(request, 'somelink.com', context)` , it possible? or any other solution? and also i want to send context parameters

why i not using media_url upload to local? cause i have limited disk, and other problem when i do production i cant load media_url, ignore this case, cause i already try many solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to render it server side, you will need to fetch the template (the `.html` file) and render it.
You can do it using the `requests` library to fetch the url template. And the Django template render engine to render the context: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

```py
import requests
from django.template import Template, Context

template = requests.get('somelink.com').content
t = Template(template)
c = Context(context)
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Notes:

1. It can worse the response time from your server.
2. As you are concerned about space, you can try to use a front-end solution to render data from your server via API.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: This is cool, that's work, but i want try front-end solution via API. Thanks for solution.

sorry may be this anohter question, do you know to create rest_framework showing data related to foreign key? ex: `author` foreign key to `user`. and i want to show that user too in one query API

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but I recommend you to check this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects